# Scala. Eclipse. SBT crashes on pattern matching and say nothing. SBT bug?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, sbt

Sorry for a long message - a hope, you'll read it.
I started to do my course work on Scala. It is FTP server. It is using patter-matching for command recognizing. I write my code in Eclipse. I think, SBT have a bug, but I don't know where to say about it.

Description:
Long compile time. After compilation there is no any error in IDE. But there is next line in "Problems" panel:

> The SBT builder crashed while compiling your project. This is a bug in
>   the Scala compiler or SBT. Check the Erorr Log for details. The error
>   message is: ch.epfl.lamp.fjbg.JCode$OffsetTooBigException: offset too
>   big to fit in 16 bits: 38838  FTPDaemon       Unknown Scala Problem

But program starts and works. Next error in run-time:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class
>   file  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     at
>   org.egslava.ftp.ControlConnection.(ControlConnection.scala:14)
>     at org.egslava.ftp.Main$.main(Main.scala:38)    at
>   org.egslava.ftp.Main.main(Main.scala)

This error is showed when I do 
new ControlConnection().start();
ControlConnection use variable currentState (pointer to abstract class FtpState). Current state may be instance of DoLogin class or WaitForCommandsState class.

WaitForCommands contains next block of code:

```
message match{  
case owner.Noop() => "200 NOOP ok\r\n";     
case owner.User(_) => "530 Can't change from guest user\r\n";   
case owner.Pass(_) => "230 Already logged in\r\n";  
case owner.Pasv() => pasv() + "\r\n";   case owner.List() => list() + "\r\n";   
case "condition" => "error";    
case owner.Nlst() => nlst() + "\r\n";   
case owner.TypeCMD() => ""//"200 Switching to binary mode\r\n";
case "PWD" => "257 \"" + currentDirectory + "\"\r\n";   
case "SITE HELP" => "200-\r\n200\r\n";  
case owner.Cwd(path) => "250 Directory successfuly changed\r\n";
case "condition2" => "error2"   
case unrecognizedCommand => "500 Unrecognized command " + unrecognizedCommand + "\r\n"; 
}
```

If I comment string (any):
    case "condition" => "error";
or
    case "condition2" => "error2"
The error will disappear.

What is it?

Comment: This isn't a specific eclipse problem, but a Scala compiler issue. See my comment to Dave Griffith's answer.

Answer (score 2):

There algorithm for compilation of pattern matching will fail on overly large case statements, by producing bytecode longer than the maximum allowed for a JVM class.  As I understand it, this is to be fixed in Scala 2.10.

Comment: Thanks. I will use many small match-sections instead of one large. But why there is no one error in compile-time. There is no even warning. I make this error - code is working, I calmy go to drink tea, and when I came back to coding, I meet this error. I thought, this is a magic :)
Where is the place for placing scala bug-reports?

Comment: +1 This is correct, but isn't an Eclipse problem, it's a generic Scala problem. The bug is https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1133 nested extractors generate exponential-space bytecode, and is fixed in 2.10 with the -Yvirtpatmat flag.